# Cannot compile Spring Boot to native image with Python language support

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, graalpython

I'm trying to build a native image (GraalVM 22.3) from a Spring Boot 3 RC1 application with Python language support on Apple M1. I can build the native image without Python language support. But when adding

```
<buildArgs combine.children="append">
    <buildArg>--verbose</buildArg>
    <buildArg>--language:python</buildArg>
    <buildArg>-Dorg.graalvm.launcher.relative.python.home=${env.JAVA_HOME}/languages/python</buildArg>
    <buildArg>-Dorg.graalvm.launcher.relative.llvm.home=${env.JAVA_HOME}/languages/llvm</buildArg> 
</buildArgs>
```

without any polyglot code in the application, the build throws errors during the "Parsing methods" step. The error message is not always the same. It differs randomly (from my point of view):

```
[4/7] Parsing methods...      [****]                                                                    (17.8s @ 4.40GB)

Fatal error: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: Discovered an unresolved callee while parsing org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:128).
    at parsing org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:128)
    at method: RequestAttributes org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2518)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:110)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3393)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.HostedBytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(HostedGraphBuilderPhase.java:201)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3345)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3190)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.HostedBytecodeParser.build(HostedGraphBuilderPhase.java:144)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:97)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:446)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.defaultParseFunction(CompileQueue.java:1145)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.doParse(CompileQueue.java:857)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue$ParseTask.run(CompileQueue.java:386)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalHelpQuiescePool(ForkJoinPool.java:2104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(ForkJoinPool.java:3321)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.complete(CompletionExecutor.java:243)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.parseAll(CompileQueue.java:594)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.finish(CompileQueue.java:424)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:651)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:610)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: Discovered an unresolved callee while parsing org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:128).
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.shouldNotReachHere(VMError.java:68)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.lookupMethodInPool(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupMethod(BytecodeParser.java:4206)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1648)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5288)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3385)
    ... 30 more
```

Other error message:

```
[4/7] Parsing methods...      [****]                                                                    (19.9s @ 2.51GB)

2 fatal errors detected:
Fatal error: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.vm.ci.meta.JavaType.toJavaName()" because "type" is null
    at parsing org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService.addDefaultFormatters(DefaultFormattingConversionService.java:110)
    at method: void org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService.addDefaultFormatters(FormatterRegistry)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2518)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:110)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3393)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.HostedBytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(HostedGraphBuilderPhase.java:201)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3345)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3190)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.HostedBytecodeParser.build(HostedGraphBuilderPhase.java:144)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:97)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:446)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.defaultParseFunction(CompileQueue.java:1145)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.doParse(CompileQueue.java:857)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue$ParseTask.run(CompileQueue.java:386)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.vm.ci.meta.JavaType.toJavaName()" because "type" is null
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedType(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:290)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedNewInstance(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:204)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4501)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4494)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5291)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3385)
    ... 23 more
Fatal error: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.vm.ci.meta.JavaType.toJavaName()" because "type" is null
    at parsing org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.format.WebConversionService.addFormatters(WebConversionService.java:70)
    at method: void org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.format.WebConversionService.addFormatters(DateTimeFormatters)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2518)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:110)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3393)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.HostedBytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(HostedGraphBuilderPhase.java:201)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3345)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3190)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.HostedBytecodeParser.build(HostedGraphBuilderPhase.java:144)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:97)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:446)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.defaultParseFunction(CompileQueue.java:1145)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue.doParse(CompileQueue.java:857)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.code.CompileQueue$ParseTask.run(CompileQueue.java:386)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.vm.ci.meta.JavaType.toJavaName()" because "type" is null
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedType(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:290)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedNewInstance(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:204)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4501)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4494)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5291)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3385)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, tracked here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4473